# terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   string s;
    cin>>s;
    int i;
    char c;
    for(i=1;i<=sizeof(s);i++){
        if((s.at(i)>='a'&&s.at(i)<='z')||(s.at(i)>='A'&&s.at(i)    <='Z')){
            c=c+4;
            if((s.at(i)>'Z'&&s.at(i)<'\136')||(s.at(i)>'z')){
                c=c-26;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

//terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string

Answer (score 2):

Problems I see:

1. You need to use `s.length()` instead of `sizeof(s)`.
2. You need to use index values starting at `0`, not `1`.
3. You need to use `i < ...` instead of `i <= ...`.

All of the above are in the `for` statement. Use:

```
for(i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
```

If you are able to use a C++11 compiler, you can simplify that to:

```
for( auto ch : s ){
  // Use ch instead of s.at(i) in the loop.
}
```

And then, you are using

```
c = c + 4;
```

and

```
c = c - 26;
```

even though you have not initialized `c`. That causes undefined behavior. I am not able to suggest a fix for that since you have not explained what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: Maybe you could also show him a range based for solution, which would take care mistakes 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Thank you so much.